# conceptually why a sliding block accelerates the wedge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Conceptually why does a sliding block impart acceleration to the wedge, but a stationary block doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is the answer. If the body is stationary, it implies the net force=0.

Furthermore, Body slides on Incline If the slant counteracts the friction but further for the incline to move the contact force has to be sufficiently high between the object and the incline for the incline to overpower friction from the surface. Consider these parameters while thinking of the problem.

Comment: Let's not get friction into the picture. The only force present is that of gravity and it is present in both the cases. The FBDs of both the cases look similar ?

Comment: Why would a body not move on an incline if there is no friction? If there is no friction, For even the slightest slant, it shall slide. A body can't stay stationary on an incline until unless external force is applied. Please correct your data, Your FBDs are perhaps wrong, It would be better if you could attach the file with the question so the error can be corrected.

Comment: I get it, thank you